# Why there is no rounding error in calculations inside fmt.Print(...)?

Tags: go

There is a rounding error in the code below and it works as expected due to calculations with float numbers according to [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats):

```
a := 0.1
b := 0.2
fmt.Println(a+b) // 0.30000000000000004
```

My question is why this code displays 0.3:

```
fmt.Print(0.1 + 0.2) // 0.3
```

Comment: [Constant Expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_expressions)

Comment: @JimB Actually can not find an answer by provided link, could you please explain?

Comment: The link is just the relevant specification reference. The marked duplicate explains the answer in more detail.